# Xamarin App Closes immediately on startup

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

Hello
I have installed **VS studio 2017 community** with xamarin tools and created a new Android project . When I attempt to launch the App it opens and closes immediately (in a blink of an eye) and no error appears.
I used Android device monitor to see whats the problem and I get this

```
 04-13 17:50:41.162: E/AndroidRuntime(16229): Process: xApp1.xApp1, PID: 16229
 04-13 17:50:41.162: E/AndroidRuntime(16229): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider mono.MonoRuntimeProvider: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
 Unable to find application Mono.Android.DebugRuntime!
 04-13 17:50:41.162: E/AndroidRuntime(16229):   at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5536)
 04-13 17:50:41.162: E/AndroidRuntime(16229):   at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5106)
 04-13 17:50:41.162: E/AndroidRuntime(16229):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5031)
 04-13 17:50:41.162: E/AndroidRuntime(16229):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:185)
 04-13 17:50:41.162: E/AndroidRuntime(16229):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1628)
 04-13 17:50:41.162: E/AndroidRuntime(16229):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
 04-13 17:50:41.162: E/AndroidRuntime(16229):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
 04-13 17:50:41.162: E/AndroidRuntime(16229):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5847)
 04-13 17:50:41.162: E/AndroidRuntime(16229):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 04-13 17:50:41.162: E/AndroidRuntime(16229):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
 04-13 17:50:41.162: E/AndroidRuntime(16229):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1010)
 04-13 17:50:41.162: E/AndroidRuntime(16229):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
 04-13 17:50:41.162: E/AndroidRuntime(16229): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find application Mono.Android.DebugRuntime!
 04-13 17:50:41.162: E/AndroidRuntime(16229):   at mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.attachInfo(MonoRuntimeProvider.java:47)
 04-13 17:50:41.162: E/AndroidRuntime(16229):   at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5533)
 04-13 17:50:41.162: E/AndroidRuntime(16229):   ... 11 more
 04-13 17:50:41.162: E/AndroidRuntime(16229): Caused by: android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: Mono.Android.DebugRuntime
 04-13 17:50:41.162: E/AndroidRuntime(16229):   at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getApplicationInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:296)
 04-13 17:50:41.162: E/AndroidRuntime(16229):   at mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.attachInfo(MonoRuntimeProvider.java:41)
 04-13 17:50:41.162: E/AndroidRuntime(16229):   ... 12 more
```

Comment: I have same ploblem.
After that I have uninstall/disable many zen app and try again it's work!

Comment: But I don't have any solution for target user with zenfone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution.
My device is Meizu M2 Note which have flymeOs 5 on it (android 5.1). 

Since it has 2 modes : normal mode and **guest mode**, when debugging, the app installs in both modes. So all what I have to do is to log into guest mode and delete the apps.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

1. `adb uninstall <package name>`
2. `adb uninstall Mono.Android.DebugRuntime`
3. `adb uninstall Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_X` (Where X is the API level)

This should set your environment to a fresh state and redeploying should work. If you need to get a list of packages to see what API level is installed, use `adb shell pm list packages -f`

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't work for me, I changed the device and the app worked normally. I think there is some files kept behind I need to root my device and delete them.

Comment: Another test is to change the package name of your app and try to deploy.

Comment: And double check to make sure you are removing the `obj` and `bin` folders between your deploys.